# Performing a command after while loop ended

Tags: bash

I'm trying to find a way to use the `while` loop to check for a certain condition, and if this condition is met, another command will be executed.

For example:

```sh
while [ -z "$(ls -A test-dir)" ];
do
  echo "directory is empty, checking again in 5 seconds"
  sleep 5
done
```

This loop will end once the directory will have any files inside, I'm trying to find a proper way to execute another command at the end when the loop completed.

Comment: What do you mean? The commands between `do` and `done` are only executed if the condition is met.

Comment: As an aside, [don't parse `ls` output.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: So, there's a proper way to check if the directory is empty or not? @tripleee

Comment: You can check if the wildcard `test-dir/*` expands to one or more files. Admittedly it's not entirely straightforward.

Comment: Or look at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/204572/57293

Answer (score 1):

Figured out that I need to simply add the last command after the while:

```sh
while [ -z "$(ls -A test-dir)" ];
do
  sleep 2
  echo "sleeping 2 seconds"
done
echo "reached the end"
```

The last command will be executed only after the loop is done.